# Rule of 5 - C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Source/Context:

[What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

[Rule-of-Three becomes Rule-of-Five with C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)

> The C++ Programming Language 4th Edition June 2013 - 
>   Section 17.1 Introduction  483
>
> ```
> class X {
> X(Sometype);  // ‘‘ordinar y constructor’’: create an object
> X();  // default constructor
> X(const X&); // copy constructor
> X(X&&);  // move constructor
> X& operator=(const X&); // copy assignment: clean up target and copy
> X& operator=(X&&); // move assignment: clean up target and move
> ˜X();  // destructor: clean up
> // ...
> };
> ```
>
> There are five situations in which an object is copied or moved: • As
>   the source of an assignment • As an object initializer • As a function
>   argument • As a function return value • As an exception In all cases,
>   the copy or move constructor will be applied (unless it can be
>   optimized away). In addition to the initialization of named objects
>   and objects on the free store, constructors are used to initialize
>   temporary objects (§6.4.2) and to implement explicit type conversion
>   (§11.5). Except for the ‘‘ordinary constructor,’’ these special member
>   functions can be generated by the compiler; see §17.6. This chapter is
>   full of rules and technicalities. Those are necessary for a full
>   understanding, but most people just learn the general rules from
>   examples.

To clarify the concepts in my mind I created a simple X class.

I'm looking for suggestions how my X class could be improved & to check I've not missed something(s)?

I've include a main() for testing; each function prints to std::cout when called.

One thing I don't fully understand: 
Why use `mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize]() : 0)` instead of: `mArray(mSize)` ?

```
X(std::size_t size = 0)                                                      
                : mSize(size),
                  mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize]() : 0)
            {
                // Default constructor
                // Initialize via constructor
                std::cout << "RETURN: X(std::size_t)" << std::endl;
    }
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class X {
    private:
        std::size_t mSize;
        int* mArray;
        void swap(X& other) noexcept
        {
            // Enable ADL (not necessary in our case, but good practice)
            // using std::swap;
            // By swapping the member(s) of two classes,
            // The two classes are effectively swapped
            std::swap(this->mSize, other.mSize);
            std::swap(this->mArray, other.mArray);
        }

    public:
        X(std::size_t size = 0)                                                      
            : mSize(size),
              mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize]() : 0)
        {
            // Default constructor
            // Initialize via constructor
            std::cout << "RETURN: X(std::size_t)" << std::endl;
        }                               
        X(const X& other)                                                                
            : mSize(other.mSize),                                                   
              mArray(mSize ? new int[mSize] : 0)
        {
            // Copy constructor 
            // Initialize via constructor
            // Note: 
            // Non-throwing because of data types being used; more attention to detail with regards
            // to exceptions must be given in a more general case, however
            std::copy(other.mArray, other.mArray + mSize, mArray);
            std::cout << "RETURN: X(const X&)" << std::endl;
        }                   
        X(X&& other)                                                            
            : X()                                                               
        {
            // Move constructor
            // C++11 only: Initialize via Default constructor X() 
            swap(std::move(other));         
            std::cout << "RETURN: X(X&&)" << std::endl;
        }                       

        X& operator=(X& rhs)
            // ?Copy assignment: 
            // Swap LHS with temp RHS - LHS resources released when function returns.
            // Strong exception guarantee. 
            // Self-assignment test not required. 
            // Duplicate code avoided.  
        {               
            X temp(rhs);                
            swap(temp);         
            std::cout << "RETURN: X& operator=(const X&)" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }       
        X& operator=(X&& rhs)   
            // Move assignment: 
            // Swap LHS with RHS - LHS resources released when function returns.
            // Duplicate code avoided.
        {
            swap(std::move(rhs));                   
            std::cout << "RETURN: X& operator=(X&&)" << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }           
        virtual ~X()                                
        {
            // Destructor: clean up
            delete[] mArray;
            std::cout << "RETURN: virtual ~X()" << std::endl;
        }   

};


int main() {

    std::cout << "X(std::size_t size);  -  Default constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  CALL: X var1(1)" << std::endl;
    X var1(1);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "X();  -  Default constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  CALL: X var2 = X()" << std::endl;
    X var2 = X();   
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "X(const X&);  -  Copy constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---------------------------------" << std::endl;
    X temp(3);
    std::cout << "  CALL: X var3(temp)" << std::endl;
    X var3(temp);
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "X(X&&); - Move constructor" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  CALL: X var4( std::move(X(4)) )" << std::endl;
    X var4( std::move(X(4)) );
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "X& operator=(const X&); - Copy assignment: clean up target and copy" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    X var5 = X(5);
    std::cout << "  CALL: temp = var5;" << std::endl;       
    temp = var5;
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "X& operator=(X&&); - Move assignment: clean up target and move" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  CALL: var2 = std::move(X(2))" << std::endl;
    var2 = std::move(X(2));
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I'm [quite critical of the copy-and-swap idiom](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/34489q/why_do_we_need_the_copy-and-swap_idiom/cqrg6zz?context=3); a copy-and-move makes more sense IMHO. Not everyone agrees with me, though.

Comment: This question is off-topic as `X` is completely generic. You are welcome to ask another question about a class that has a clear purpose.

Comment: @Veedrac: Will since a move is usually implemented as a swap (because 1) You can't delete until after the state has been completely changed 2) The src must by in a valid state agter the move) I don't think it makes that much difference. The name is a hangover from pre C++11 when when we did not have move.

Comment: @Veedrac: But if you can write an answer to this question [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/14065) and explain the improvement achieved by copy and move I will happily vote on it.

Comment: @LokiAstari Something like https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/978c91238ac681323524. It's not much different, but I think it's cleaner.

Comment: @200_success - X is completely generic on purpose so we can focus on the rule of 5, however the class does have a clear purpose in that it manages an array thus requiring the Rule of 5. This is not "someone else's code" this is my implementation of the Rule of 5 after reading on the subject from many different sources. Also, it is a functioning and concrete example. There is no need for some other code that only exists in your imagination...now that is off topic! - I think you need to go back and re-read the question I asked!

Comment: @Veedrac - I like the simplicity of your copy-and-move, but I ran my OP test main() one thousand times against both idioms and surprisingly found copy-and-swap called fewer functions and was 18.94% quicker.  Not sure how much this matters?
See bottom for execution times: 
http://s7.postimg.org/fcw9u9fpn/image.jpg

Comment: @tuk [My compilers won't even accept your code](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/6abe18505d4ed174983b), which makes me feel that any time differences are likely to be due to your undefined behaviour. Further, there's literally *no way* that the times you give are anything other than the time for the console to print. On top of that, the code is going to be almost completely elided with optimizations, bar the printing. I might do some proper timings later, but don't take your test to mean much.

Comment: @Veedrac - My code runs error free in VS2013/VS2015. Running main() one hundred thousand times against both idioms( without console printing ) showed your copy-and-move as being 14.18% faster.

Comment: @tuk Don't trust VS! Clang and GCC both agree with me here. I had to fix your code a tad to make it compile. // I wasn't sure how to time something so evidently quick, but I threw together [some benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/8331ebd66781d51cccd5) compiled with optimizations and got exactly the same time for both of them. The only expensive part is actually the overhead in the loop or allocations when I include them, so you evidently can't perceive a difference. The point being that there's absolutely no way that the time difference you gave is reasonable.

Comment: You can do way more than 100m moves a second, so looping 100k times makes a difference of no more than a millisecond.

Comment: @Veedrac - Can you explain a bit more about "Almost a swap, but it doesn't have to be." for eg Why **std::swap(data, other.data);** and not  **data = other.data** ..why not just move it, as you did with **size** ?

Comment: @tuk `data = other.data` would require deallocating `data` and zeroing the other class' to prevent double frees. That takes more effort. (Further, keeping the old data around for longer means it can be reused (eg. in the next copy assignment) - I haven't done that but many classes, like `std::vector`, will.)

Comment: @Veedrac How would you resue it, if the size is wrong after move `operator=`? Your move `operator=` seems to leave the object `other` in a strange state with size and size of data not matching.

Comment: @rozina If you wanted to reuse the allocation after a move-from, you could use `realloc`. Ergo you don't need to keep the size around. If you wanted to reuse without reallocating, you'd probably want to `std::swap` the size too. My code doesn't bother, so I don't do that bookkeeping.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an exhaustive answer.

> One thing I don't fully understand: Why use mArray(mSize ? new intmSize : 0) instead of: mArray(mSize) ?

Because you need to initialize the array with a pointer, not with an integer.

```
X(X&&other)
: X()                                                               
{
    // Move constructor
    // C++11 only: Initialize via Default constructor X() 
    swap(std::move(other));         
    std::cout << "RETURN: X(X&&)" << std::endl;
}
```

Your constructor calls swap, which receives a reference (meaning you are actually creating a copy here).

Either way, you don't need to write your own swap for this class.

For this constructor, consider this implementation:

```
X::X(X&& other)
: mSize(other.mSize), mArray(other.mArray)
{
     other.mSize = 0;
     other.mArray = nullptr;
}
```

Implement a single copy assignment operator, using copy&swap:

```
X& operator=(X rhs) // pass by value
// Strong exception guarantee. 
{               
    // X temp(rhs); // copy already created in received argument
    using std::swap;
    swap(*this, rhs);

    std::cout << "RETURN: X& operator=(const X&)" << std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```

Other stuff:

Use `nullptr` instead of zero.

Either make the class final and the destructor non-virtual, or leave the destructor virtual and remove the assignment operators. Having an assignment operator in a base class leads to getting your objects sliced.

```
var2 = std::move(X(2));
```

`X(2)` is a rvalue; you don't need the move call (just write `var2 = X{2};`).

Comment: Executing main() { **temp = var5** } creates a Stack overflow Exception at: X& operator=(X rhs) { **std::swap(*this, rhs)** }